# Heroku Memory management. What is the maximum amount of memory per worker

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

It might be a trivial question, but I feel like I need to ask this question:

When Heroku says that I have 512 MB of RAM, and 10 process types, does this mean I have 512MB of RAM per each process, or the 512MB is divided by the number of processes I use, e.g 512MB/10 = 51.2MB per process?

If it's the latter, doesn't it make the unlimited number of processes in Heroku useless? I don't understand this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each dyno is an independent container running on a different instance. You can see them as a different server.
That means each running process will get it's own memory and CPU. The 512MB are therefore not divided by the number of processes.

Comment: Does this mean each process type is a dyno? For example: They say that I have 512MB | 10 process types. Does this mean I have 512MB per each process?

Comment: `heroku ps:scale web=2 worker=1` --> does this command mean I have 3 dynos that I pay for? and each of them is 512MB ram?

Comment: Yes, each process type is a dyno and the scale command you provided means you have 3 dynos that you will pay for, each of them having 512MB ram.

Comment: If you use the Heroku dashboard to scale your processes, you can see how much the monthly cost should be (if you run 24/7 all month).  You can see the costs before you apply the scaling.  There are a few dyno options that affect costs